# Flags marked as helpful, review completed, but flagged post not deleted

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, review-queues, flags

Ever since not-an-answer flags have been routed via the Low Quality Posts queue, I've had a number of cases where my flag has been marked as helpful, the review has been completed with a majority-delete verdict, but the post was never deleted.

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4763210
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4770087

Does anyone know what will cause this situation? How will the system ensure the deletion of these posts?

Comment: VLQ review is complete when there are 6 Recommend Delete votes, then the post should get auto deleted. In both cases, the answer got positive score (2 and 3 actually) so my guess it's a bug, since the team never expected VLQ answers to have positive score.

Comment: If the above is correct, either don't let us flag positive scored answer as NAA or delete them despite their score.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm reading the system flags correctly, it's the positive scores on these answers that's preventing them from being automatically deleted by review.

I believe these system flags are raised to us for a second opinion. I've converted one of the answers to a comment and deleted the other (because "psst hey here's your answer [click here to see the answer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0) it's in the link" ugh it *stinks* so bad).

Comment: Yes, any post which reaches the deletion threshold in review that also has a positive score will raise an auto-flag for us rather than being automatically deleted.

Comment: Humm. Shame we can't track the outcome of these auto-flags. I assume the auto-flags in this instance were still in your queue then?

Comment: @Matt Heh, there's currently over 100 "disputed low quality review" flags in our queue...

Comment: @animuson: Ah, another case of too many mods enjoying their weekends... :P

Comment: @Matt I blame their mothers.

Comment: Even if that deleted answer referred to a YouTube video that actually answered the question: what's up with folks answering using videos? I kind of hope it's just a way to promote YouTube channels while expecting to make some money out of that. Or do some really think it's easer to watch, e.g., http://youtu.be/E9C89jxzUjY and http://youtu.be/0aCohn2hJzg rather than being given only the necessary steps as simple text? (Both examples once posted on Super User but luckily deleted, and both also with incredibly annoying background music.)