# Don't put positive scored answers flagged as NAA in the VLQ queue

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review-queues, low-quality-posts, not-an-answer

As can be seen [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254363/flags-marked-as-helpful-review-completed-but-flagged-post-not-deleted), answers with score 1 or more can't be deleted, by design, even after getting 6 Recommend Deletion votes in the VLQ review.

I accept this and it makes sense, so please don't send such answers to the VLQ review queue in the first place as it's quite pointless.

Comment: Just because they have positive scores does not mean they are any less NAA. And for that matter where else do you propose they be sent to?

Comment: It's not pointless. If the answer *shouldn't* be deleted, then it will attract Looks Good responses and won't bother moderators at all.

Comment: @BoltClock but only moderators can actually delete them. So maybe just hide/disable the Recommend Deletion button for such answers?

Comment: As Brad and animuson note, review still serves a very important function here, namely that of filtering out spurious flags on reasonable answers - and between a third and a half of all NAA flags on upvoted answers *are* spurious.

Comment: Thanks @Shog as I've commented on Brad's answer myself, totally agree with declining this request.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It actually isn't pointless. It helps us identify upvoted non-answers, because when such an answer receives unanimous "delete" votes in review, it automatically casts a special flag for us stating

> disputed low quality review (auto): Post has a good score but received
>   delete votes

This usually highlights non-answers that somehow got upvoted, and we can delete those if needed. I've also been using that to find bad reviewers who upvoted those posts blindly to begin with.

Also, several of these answers that are being flagged would still be useful as comments, so it can help to pick those out.

The other ones that aren't non-answers are identified and removed by "looks good" votes in the queue, so that reduces our overall workload with these.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks! So by all means, decline this request. :)