# Why is "Review Completed" when post not yet deleted?

Tags: support, review-queues, low-quality-posts

Link to review: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9939800)
Link to "answer": [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377964/no-such-file-or-directory-error-in-codeblocks/33274334#33274334)

Quite clearly the answer should be deleted, as it's not even close to being an answer. Yet the review is completed, and the answer is still there. I've seen [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299373/why-is-a-post-with-six-recommended-deletion-votes-still-not-deleted) [questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254363/flags-marked-as-helpful-review-completed-but-flagged-post-not-deleted) where this happens because the answer has a positive score, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

What is the cause of this? What actions complete  a review queue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, editing will complete a LQP review and void all Recommend Delete votes if the post doesn't get deleted first, on the presumption that if a post was worth editing, then "clearly" it was anything but unsalvageable.

And this is why you *do not* edit other people's answers that are clearly NAA. You can't salvage a NAA without completely changing its meaning. It doesn't work that way. So don't waste your time (and others').

Comment: Thanks. This didn't occur to me as a potential cause, as I didn't notice how close the "Edit" was to the subsequent "Recommend Deletion".

Comment: Maybe _Edit if you can fix all the problems with this answer_ (from the review instruction) isn't clear enough - we might want to add that unsalvagable answers **must not** be edited? Recently, the inappropriate editing seems to happen more frequently and consequently I have to re-flag NAAs (from the late answers) with custom mod attention flags to get them deleted