# When is NAA or VLQ flag deemed helpful but post is not deleted?

Tags: discussion

What are the current rules on when raised NAA or VLQ flag is deemed helpful but post is not deleted?

Normally when I raise either of these 2 flags it's marked as helpful and post is deleted either by community in review process, delete votes or moderator but recently raised 2 NAA flags on these 2 new answers to old questions

- [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293217/ajax-uncaught-reference-error/36128778#36128778) (now deleted)
- [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532926/this-value-is-null-in-function-react-native/36149749#36149749) (now also deleted)

In both cases flags where marked as helpful but answers have not been deleted. I've read these questions regarding similar problem

[Flags marked as helpful, review completed, but flagged post not deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254363/flags-marked-as-helpful-review-completed-but-flagged-post-not-deleted)

[Why is my not an answer flag marked helpful but not acted on?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275063/why-is-my-not-an-answer-flag-marked-helpful-but-not-acted-on)

and answers with positive score won't be automatically deleted but in my case one has score or -2 and other has no votes at all. Now, in the first case I though it's because post has been edited after flag has been raised but second answer has not been edited and both went through Low Quality Queue, judging by comments.

Does edit make NAA/VLQ flag helpful?

Why would second answer flag be deemed helpful but post not removed?

In either case should I raise different flag type (VLQ?) since cannot raise NAA flag more then once?

Comment: You might want to read my post where I made a recap http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318952/1743880

Comment: Answer 2 was undeleted by OP after it was deleted in review http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36149749/timeline

Comment: @Floern thanks, didn't check there. But would delete/undelete not show as if the post has been edited?

Comment: *Does edit make NAA/VLQ flag helpful?* Edits in the queue make NAA flags helpful and all edits make VLQ flags helpful.

Comment: Looks like a bug, the poster could probably undelete it because he was the first one to delete the post.

Comment: @Kendra yup - tried to explain that in my (rather more verbose than I planned) answer :p

Comment: @HansPassant [author disagreement with review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184568/165773 "explained here") undeletes their post - this is by design (though such undeletion gets escalated to mod attention with system flag)

Comment: @JonClements Glad to see I was correct in my guess on what happened. I'll clean up my comment, since your answer covers it well. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**re: Answer 1**:

This went into the low quality review queue (because of your NAA flag) and received a recommend deletion from one user and an edit from another. The edit cleared it from the queue and automatically marked your NAA flag helpful. You then re-flagged as VLQ and the community didn't get around to handle the VLQ flag before it entered the mod queue and a mod deleted it appropriately - also marking your VLQ flag helpful.

**re: Answer 2**:

Again, you flagged this as NAA - so it entered the review queue and received 6 recommend deletion votes. These aren't "proper" delete votes as such (in contrast to votes by 20k+ users) - so although the end result is that the post is deleted - the OP is still able to undelete with a single vote.

I'm supposing the rationale behind this is that the OP has another chance to take into account the answer may not be appropriate (or potentially give leniency to the OP in case of heavy handed reviewers), edit it, then undelete it. What happens here is that an auto flag is raised in the moderator queue for a "disputed low quality review" (with a note that "Post was undeleted by the author") - in this case, a mod reviewed it and again appropriately deleted the post.

Note that in the case of the post receiving actual delete votes rather than recommended ones the OP if they have the required rep (10k+) will only be able to cast an undelete vote which will require two more to undelete - this means: the OP will not be able to single handedly undelete.

**General**

As the system works at the moment (although meta is fairly active in other ideas/suggestions) - using NAA was correct in both cases. In some cases, you may find a flag marked helpful in cases where a moderator thinks the flag was made in good faith and in accordance with today's standards of flagging, but it may have been made on a post from years ago (obviously not in this case), where standards were different, and although the post may not be great, as long as it isn't causing harm, has helped people etc., it may not necessarily be considered for deletion (which in effect the NAA/VLQ flags are requesting).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and just to clarify was my action to re-flag as VLQ in the first case appropriate or should I leave it or use different flag type like custom moderator flag? My thinking was that since they feed same queue it can be resolved within community therefore no need to involve moderator with custom flag.

Comment: @dkozl - Either way should work. I'm of the opinion that edits should not clear these flags or [should provide a disputed flag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230665/edits-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue-clear-out-the-flag-and-dont-generate-any-d), because I've seen a ton of non-answers be allowed to live due to mistaken edits. The next best thing is to somehow let people know that a mistake was made when the post was edited, so either a custom flag or another "not an answer" / "very low quality" flag will do that.

Comment: @BradLarson Perhaps a checkbox should be provided for editors above a certain rep limit along the lines of 'this edit resolves the flags cast against the post' - in which case it's removed from the review queue, otherwise it is not.

Comment: The review actually received 4 recommend deletes and 2 deletes - at what point does it count as a real delete (or do all the votes have to be a delete vote?)